# What is the size of TypeORM's logger file ormlogs.log?

Tags: javascript, database, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

With this connection configuration

```
{
    name: "mysql",
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "test",
    password: "test",
    database: "test",
    logging: true,
    logger: "file",
}
```

which creates ormlogs.log file in root folder, what is the max size of this logger file?
How can we check max size of it or how can we set it for specific size?

The file was too big like more than 10 GB and I had problem in getting response from the code.

Comment: In this case you will need to create a [custom logger](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/logging#using-custom-logger) that can handle such logic. You can also filter which logs to store using `logging: ["error", "warn"]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

@pratik_a, I don't know about the set specific size, but you can set for [queries which run for more than x seconds](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/logging#log-long-running-queries), set specific [types of log you need more](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/logging#logging-options) or create your strategy with logs using [Custom Logger](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/logging#using-custom-logger)